# Thaumometer on bed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thaumcraft

I just started playing with Thaumcraft, and I scanned my bed at night with a thaumometer and was transported to another world. I woke up midday in a small hut with a bed and rug and fire, and outside there was somewhat large landmasses (the one i was on was not nearly as big) and they were above the clouds with no land connecting the landmasses in between. I also saw a giant zombie (he was so big that trees were dwarfed next to him) and when I scanned him nothing could be learned. He started coming towards me slowly but made no noise. Then I shot an arrow at him and it did nothing. I got scared I was going to die so I ran back to the hut and scanned the bed there, and was reported back to my original house at night.
**Can someone tell me what's going on here??**

Comment: I don't remember exactly, and this seems to be a different version from what I played originally, but that "other world" sounds like a newer version of the [Twilight Forest](http://ftbwiki.org/Twilight_Forest).

Comment: I assume you're playing a modpack? Do you know which mods you have loaded?

Comment: thanks, this looked very different tho. Im using the thaumcraft mod that came in the legacy mod pack along with some others in that pack. i could only find info on the zombie i saw and it seems like he is the unused giant

Comment: So I been exploring the overworld a lot, and ended up over 4800m from my start location according to my minimap, and when i went into the dreamworld there, i found a town that was populated by pig people. They weren't zombie pigmen, but looked like your average overworld pig but standing upright and living in this town. I had 7 armor filled on that armor bar, and 2 hits from them killed me (i didn't know they were hostile). It seemed to be a town of pigmen before they became zombie pigmen. I want to explore that town and see what's in there next

Comment: There were also these really cartoony looking villagers there, but only a couple. I couldn't get close enough before I died, but it looked like one was a girl in a frog costume and the other was green skinned in a purple outfit. The rest were pigmen. Has anyone came across this'/

Comment: @Nico Do you have Witchery in your game? That mod adds such a thing.

Comment: @Nico Those villagers you are referring to are Beast Boy and Rana, two of the original Minecraft player models/NPCs that were removed in 2010.

Answer (score 5):

That sounds like the [Rediscovered Mod](http://www.minecraftmods.com/rediscovered-mod/). You get there by right-clicking on a bed (the fact that you were holding a thaumometer doesn't matter). It is a Sky Dimension with Giants and Pigman Villages, among other things...

> The Rediscovered Mod adds a bunch of blocks, mobs, and items that were either concepts or only around briefly in Minecraft history.

[image]

And just for the record, if you want to scan right-clickable things with a thaumometer you have to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> for the scanning to work.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a 100% certain answer, but if the grass in this world was a pastel-y blue-green then this may be one of the many Aether dimensions from one of the mods you are using.

You probably won't have done much to the giant zombie as you likely missed the hit-box as they are not well-placed on them.